# Voice calls over a Chat app using Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am trying to build a simple chat application. But it requires Voice calls functionality to other users. I would be using Firebase for messaging. Does Firebase have Voice calls support? I can configure external SIP

Comment: There is nothing built in to Firebase for supporting voice calls.

Comment: Hello Vikas. Did you implement voice calling functionality? Could you please help me on how to get started?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to create voice call or video call app, maybe you can use WebRTC technology.

WebRTC is a free, open project that provides browsers and mobile applications with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple APIs.

There is a nice presentation [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1CjuTaY2J9P5xrFDtRCh6VmS7Iw2UBbm-JEwzCHQCYkE/edit#slide=id.g521d01055_1_30)

Comment: WebRTC is not suitable for large peer count (e.g. for 25 peers chat, 300 connections are required to connect each two peers of other)

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow: Use webRTC with any sip server it will handle large number of rush

Answer (score 0):

**Java/Kotlin solution**

If you want to create voice calling system using firebase,

**Sending**

Use `AudioRecord` class for getting `audiosample` then use `Base64.encoder` to convert `audioSample(byte[])` to String. Now you can send the converted string to Database.

**Receiving**

Initiate `AudioTrack` get the String from database, use `Base64.decoder` to convert String to `byte[]`, now you can write the `byte[]` to `Audiotrack` for playback.

Comment: Why, if he can use WebRTC without database?

Comment: I don't know, Webrtc available for java or not,  and the performance of my technique and webrtc  are same, why do we add extra libs and material if we can create on own.

Comment: Why you didn't explicit that it is Java technology in your answer? Please edit your answer and explicit that this is a Java solution.

Comment: Never mind, I edited it, please check are it is OK. You can edit your answer and check how markdown works. For example, if you want to make a new line, you need to press twice enter.